# ExpandableLislView с разными картинками для групп

Tags: expandablelistview, android, adapter, изображения

Есть список expandablelist с подгруппами. Все работает как надо. Теперь нужно добавить разные изображения для групп. Пробую разные варианты и все никак. Как это можно сделать? 
спасибо за любую помощь

В **main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/exListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:indicatorLeft="350dp"
        android:indicatorRight="300dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Адаптер

```
public class ExpListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context context;

static  String []parentList={"parent1", "parent2", "parent3"};

static  String [][]childList={
{"chil1", "chil2", "child3"},
{"child1", "child2"},
{"child1", "child2", "child3", "child4"};

........
    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        TextView tv=new TextView(context);
        tv.setText(parentList[groupPosition]);
        tv.setPadding(50, 10, 10, 10);
        tv.setTextSize(25);

        return tv;
    }
......
```

Comment: в этом фрагменте кода не видно, что вы пробовали сделать.

Comment: и тут нету ни одного изображения... Или вы в TextView пытались вставить изображение?

Answer (score 1):

```
public View getGroupView(final int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.вашЛэйаут, null);

        TextView title = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        ImageView image = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.image);

        title.setText(parentList[groupPosition]);
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);

        return rootView;
    }
```